# Excel SDK for Mac

Tags: c++, macos, excel

Anyone know if there is an Excel SDK for Mac OSX for addins?
I've scanned around but not found anything yet.

Comment: Nevermind... see below for the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597509.aspx has the information for developing add-ins for Excel 2011 for Mac OSX.

Comment: Thanks, Ahmed. The link refers to windows-centric stuff whereas I was looking for the equivalent for the mac release of excel to make add-ins and rtd servers in C++.

Comment: Actually it does apply to Excel 2011 for  MacOSX versions as well... have a look carefully :-)